# How to mix the medium blog into my posts list in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, medium.com-publishing-api

Currently, I am creating my personal website: https://hantsy.github.io

And in the past 2 years, I have posted a lot of articles on Medium.

I want to add Medium indices(title, date, abstract, etc) into my posts list(/blog), and mix the medium  blog entries and my personal blog in hantsy.github.io.

1. Sort all posts(medium blog, and posts in hantsy.github.io) by date in the `/blog` page.
2. When it is a Medium blog, click it to redirect to Medium. else open it under https://hantsy.github.io/blog/year/xxx

[This post](https://medium.com/@jameshamann/displaying-medium-posts-on-your-jekyll-website-7eef230309e4) is helpful, but it is fully replacing the local posts with Medium posts.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be something like: Get medium posts as JSON and load them in the data directory and combine them with regular posts in liquid. I would love to help you further, but not on SO. Maybe on Jekyll talk or Slack.

Comment: I have reposted on Jekyll talk.

Comment: Great! And I see some great answers there.